# How to left join in sql correctly?

Tags: mysql, dynamic, tags, left-join

Im trying to left join tags on my article as per the following example:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT * 
FROM art
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON article.tag=tags.joinid
WHERE allow=1
ORDER BY date_added DESC 
LIMIT 10.
```

however it doesnt work.
How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the output? It would also help if you can provide the table structure.

Comment: Is the table name called `art` or `article`?

Comment: "article" not "art" ... typo

Comment: Could you please provide the table schema?